# imagePickerController iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

My app features picking images from camera roll and also clicking a new one and then upload.
When i pick an existing image from the camera roll it gives me an image name like asset.jpg(which is what i want), but when i click i new image it returns a memory location and not the name of image(such as asset.jpg). For getting the name as asset.jpg i have to first store the image to the camera roll using

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
            [self.imageView setImage:nil];
        }
```

which i dont want to. Is there anyway so that i can get the image name as asset.jpg for a newly clicked image without first saving the image to camera roll. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL gives the URL in case of picking an existing image from camera roll but returns a temporary memory location for the newly clicked image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset name is provided when you save the photo so you will need to do so. I use the following code to save the image and get its path.

```
   ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        // Request to save the image to camera roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation]completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetClickedURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error saving image %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else
        {

            NSLog(@"image from camera saved at  %@", assetClickedURL);
            [self uploadImageAtassetURL:assetClickedURL];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: But then my purpose of instant click and upload is not fulfilled as user again has to go to camera roll for picking the image.

Comment: Not really. I have edited the code to show where you could get the assetURL and then upload the image at that URL. By doing this the image gets saved in the photo album and then is uploaded. You will need to implement the upLoadImageAtAssetURL depending on where you are uploading too.